# cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix returns ROI of [0,0,0,0] on some data sets

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on a Python program using OpenCV 2.x Below is an exerpt of my code that runs on a list of already captured and saved files. All the images are **80x60 8-bit greyscale images**. The best that I have got is a ROI of `[1, 6, 73, 49]` for one camera, but my other camera has gotten the best ROI is `[8, 9, 55, 39]`. I am already working with such small images, throwing away ~50% of my pixels is not really a workable solution. I am just not sure what is causing `cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix()` to return such small ROI, especially when I feed it anywhere from 15-40 images that seem to have found the corners correctly.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 100, .01)
goodImages = 0

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((3*4,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:4,0:3].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

images = glob.glob('*Left.bmp')

for fname in images:
print("Working on file: %s" % (fname))
img = cv2.imread(fname,cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
gray = cv2.imread(fname,0)

# Find the chess board corners
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (4,3),None)

# If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
if ret == True:
    print("Found Corners for %s" % (fname))

    objpoints.append(objp)

    cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(3,3),(-1,-1),criteria)
    if corners is None:
        print("Something went wrong with cornerSubPix in file: %s" % (fname))
    else:
        imgpoints.append(corners)
        goodImages+=1

        # Draw and display the corners
        cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (4,3), corners,ret)
        cv2.imshow('img',img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)



if goodImages >9:           
ret, intrinsicMatrix, distortionCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)


h,  w = img.shape[:2]
refinedCameraMatrix, roi=cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(intrinsicMatrix,distortionCoeffs,(w,h),1,(w,h))

np.savez("LeftCamera", refinedCameraMatrix=refinedCameraMatrix, roi=roi, intrinsicMatrix=intrinsicMatrix, distortionCoeffs=distortionCoeffs)
```

A sample data set can be downloaded at:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=67483192025612443532

**EDIT**
I have found a data set after much trial and error that gives me a ROI of `[3, 4, 75, 53]` so the need for this question is not urgent, but I do find the question interesting. While I was experimenting I found that a good data set + another good picture does not always increase the ROI and can in fact decrease the ROI. That does not intuitively work for me, as more good data should increase the usable area.

Comment: Good question. Think I will try it...

Comment: In case it is helpful I am including a link to the best file set I have thus far. [http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=25758342279820518279](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=25758342279820518279)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

**Tl;dr: make sure the edges and corners are well represented by the checkerboard in the calibration images.**

With data only in the center, where distortion is minimal, the solution is subject to greater error.

Further discussion here.

http://answers.opencv.org/question/28438/undistortion-at-far-edges-of-image/?answer=180493#post-id-180493

Answer (score 0):

What I found out is that the criteria matters alot for this:
self.criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.1) returns good values.

self.criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.01)
returns 0 0 0 0

in other words, if you set the last term as 0.1 it might work, if it is lower... might not
(if I set the last value to 1 it also work... maybe just try to modify that value and see what works best for you)

I am still not sure what that value does but, if I set it to 0.05 it works and the picture is pixelated (scaled) and if I set it to a higher value like 5 or 10, it looks that it still works but the picture is clearer (not scaled).

Overall, if you encounter this problem just try to adjust the last value from the termination criteria.