# How do I undistort images with my camera matrix?

Tags: python, linux, opencv, raspberry-pi, camera-calibration

Extreme python noob here. I'm trying to calibrate the camera on my raspberry pi to correct for distortion. I've successfully generated my camera matrix and distortion coefficients, but now am having trouble actually using those to generate undistorted images.

Heres the code. `image0` is the picture I'm trying to undistort:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

# Define Camera Matrix
mtx =  np.array([[2.19605891e+03, 0, 1.01476828e+03],
                 [0, 2.21128295e+03, 6.35922558e+02],
                 [0, 0, 1]])

# Define distortion coefficients
dist = np.array([-1.10335088e-01, 8.29479393, 9.69372290e-04, 
                 -3.88984964e-03, -8.36301163e+01])

# Getting the new optimal camera matrix
img = cv2.imread('image0.jpg')
h, w = img.shape[:2]
newcameramtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx,dist,(w,h),1, 
                    (w,h))

# Checking to make sure the new camera materix was properly generated
print(newcameramtx)

# Undistorting
dst = cv2.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)

# Cropping the image
x,y,w,h = roi
dst = dst[y:+y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imwrite('calibresult.png',dst)
```

The code doesn't give me any errors, but whenever I try to open the supposedly undistorted image, it tells me:
`Image file '/home/pi/calibresult.png' contains no data`.

I don't know why the image is not being generated properly.

Comment: Can you re-run it and add `print(dst.shape)` right before the `cv2.imwrite` .  Also add a `print(roi)` as well.  I suspect it has something to do with your indexing on `dst`.  Then add the output to the question.

Comment: Heres the output when I added that: The new camera matrix:[[  1.57948499e+03   0.00000000e+00   1.08245447e+03]
 [  0.00000000e+00   1.78246558e+03   6.51857288e+02]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]]
 The dst.shape: (0, 0, 3)
 and the roi: (0, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: That is probably your problem as you are doing `dst[0:0, 0:0]`.  I would look at your `cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx,dist,(w,h),(w,h))` and see what isup with that.  What are `w` and `h`?

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that. w and h are the pixel width and height of the image. I'm following the guide on opencv's website almost exactly so I'm not sure why its not working. https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html

Comment: Needless to say, I would check each of the inputs to `cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix` and make sure they all make sense. I suspect it is something odd about a parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the help. All the parameters for 
cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix are indeed being generated correctly. mtx and dist are as defined and w=1920 and h=1080. I think the problem lies somewhere in cv2.undistort but I'm not sure where. I'll keep looking

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750901/cv2-getoptimalnewcameramatrix-returns-roi-of-0-0-0-0-on-some-data-sets.  Maybe that is related.