# Keep imgae resolution after undistortion process - camera calibration

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration, perspectivecamera

I am working on camera calibration using opencv in python. I’ve already done calibration using cv2.calibrateCamera and got the camera matrix and distortion coefficients. I also have evaluated the validity of camera matrix; in other words, the estimated focal lens is very close to the sensor’s focal lens in the datasheet (I know the pixel size and the focal lens in mm from the datasheet). I should mention that in order to undistort new images, I follow the instructions below; as I NEED to keep all source pixels in the undistorted images.

```
alpha = 1. # to keep all pixels
scale = 1. # to change output image size

w,h = 200,200 # original image size captured by camera
newcameramtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(camera_matrix, dist_coefs, (w,h), alpha, (int(scale2*w), int(scale2*h))))
mapx, mapy = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(camera_matrix, dist_coefs, None, newcameramtx, (w,h), 5)
dst = cv2.remap(img, mapx, mapy, cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

x_, y_, w_, h_ = roi
dst_cropped = dst[y_:y_+h_, x_:x_+w_]
```

And now the issues and my questions:

The source images are suffering high positive radial distortions, and dst images resulted from undistorsion process are satisfying and seems the positive radial distortion is already canceled, at lease visually. Because of alpha = 1. I also have all source pixels in the dst image. However, the roi is really small and it crops a region in the middle of imae. I could say that dst_cropped only contains the pixels close to the center of dst. According to the links below:

[cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix returns ROI of [0,0,0,0] on some data sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750901/cv2-getoptimalnewcameramatrix-returns-roi-of-0-0-0-0-on-some-data-sets/47841228)

https://answers.opencv.org/question/28438/undistortion-at-far-edges-of-image/?answer=180493#post-id-180493

I found that the probable issue might be because of my dataset; then I tried to balance the dataset to have more images having chessboard close to the image boundaries. I repeated the calibration and the obtained results are very close to the first trial, however still the same effect is presented in the dst_cropped images. I tried to play with alpha parameter as well, but any number less than 1. does not keep all source pixels in dst image. Considering all above information, it seems that I'm obliged to keep using dst images instead of dst_cropped ones; then another issue arises from dst size which is the same as source image (w,h). It is clear that because of alpha=1. the dst contains all source pixels as well as zero pixels, but my question is that how can keep the resolution as before. If I don't make a mistake, seems all points are mapped and then the resulted image is scaled down to fit (w,h). Then, my question is that how can I force the calibration to KEEP resolution as before? For example, if some points are mappted to (-100,-100) or (300,300) the dst should be [400,400] and not [200,200]. How to expand images instead of scaling down?

Thanks in advance for your helps or advice,

Comment: replace (int(scale2*w), int(scale2*h)) by (w,h)

Comment: sorry, it was a typo mistake while posting the question, it is (int(scale . w), int(scale . h)), I tried with different scales like 1 (which leads to (w,h)), 0.5, 1.5; but same issue.

Comment: ok, you dont want to keep the image resolution (200x200), but you want to keep the pixel size? You cant keep the pixel size everywhere during undidstortion, since you will distort/undistort pixels. So where in the image do you want to keep the pixel size? Around the principal point? You could compute a size-distortion from the map, so remapping e.g. 4 points from source to destination and measure area. If the area change is too big, change your parameters. With splines you could change your mapping per region, but probably no algorithm available and research topic.

Comment: yes, I want to keep the pixel sizes. In fact, the image boundaries are much important than around principle point. I need displacement fields / mappings for those pixels. Then, if I want to get displacement fields for ALL source pixels what should I do?

Comment: In fact, I am so confused and not sure about the given mappings. Indeed what cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap provides as mapx and mapy are mappings from target to source; this means that there is no gaurantie to have valid displacements for all source pixels to target space, by inversion of mapx and mapy. Is it possible to generate forward mapping from source to target directly from calibration matrix and dist_coefs?

Comment: matrix inversion will not work. I dont even know whether there is an inversion possibility (e.g. inverting the distortion coefficients). But you coiuld compute the area distortion in both directions

Comment: yeh, that is true, unfortunately, and thank you for your comments.